# How to check Mysql table has changed or not?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an app that is connected to the server database. I want to check if a  table has changed, then send a request to the database to get new values in the app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a service for it that constantly checks for the database then make your service pass the new data through sockets. for a standard solution, some modification on other 3rd party app will be needed like creating a socket that sends the new data to your mobile app after inserting it to the database like how firebase does.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But how can I check the table edited or inserted in MySQL?